# Init object every time file new is called

Tags: python

I'm using a Python class static members properties in order to store the state of the addon I'm developing. It works fine and my Python class is brand new every time I start Blender. Problem is, if I do file->new or revert, that class is not created anew and still stores values that are relevant to the old file. Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

**A persistent onload handler**

[Application handlers.](https://docs.blender.org/api/master/bpy.app.handlers.html#persistent-handler-example)

Code taken directly from [Persistent Handler Example](https://docs.blender.org/api/master/bpy.app.handlers.html#persistent-handler-example)

```
import bpy
from bpy.app.handlers import persistent


@persistent
def load_handler(dummy):
    print("Load Handler:", bpy.data.filepath)


bpy.app.handlers.load_post.append(load_handler)
```

Other things to consider re comment for revert and new is look at

```
bpy.data.is_dirty
```

for toggle from `True` to `False`. Wont matter if  a clean file is reverted.

Comment: Thank you. So this will work in the load case. Not in file->new or revert cases. Nice to learn about handlers though.